# Replace Self Closing Node with Paired Empty nodes in XML in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, ssis, nodes

I am writing an SSIS Package where we bring in an existing XML and then Add couple nodes to it and then spit it back out. It has to be exactly the same way it goes in and comes back out, except for the 3 new columns. I use a combination of SQL Server and C# Script in SSIS to do this.

However this is the issue:
The original XML document has these nodes for example:

```
<Base_Entry>
    <Customer></Customer>
    <Profit></Profit>
```

...

When I put the data into the database in SQL Server and then do some parsing for the other nodes and then do try to output the XML back out it comes out looking like this for the 2 nodes.

```
<Base_Entry>
   <Customer />
   <Profit />
```

Now I know that semantically the self closing node is the same as the one on top. It's for blanks. However, our vendor can't work with it and is requesting it to NOT be a self closing node. He wants it just like the original.

However I can't figure it out no matter what I do in SQL Server. Blank nodes come out with a self closing node.
I tried changing it in C# using a script task for SSIS trying to do a

```
 XMLOutput.InnerXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" + 
 Dts.Variables["XMLOutput"].Value.ToString().Replace("<Customer />", "<Customer></Customer>");
```

The XMLOutput.InnerXml has the entire XML content and I am trying to just replace the words in there manually by trying to do a Replace.

If anyone can help me out how to do it with just SQL Server first, that would be appreciated the most. IF not, is there a way to just replace it in C#?

Comment: **"...When I put the data into the database in SQL Server and then do some parsing for the other nodes and then do try to output the XML back out..."** Please share your T-SQL code. You need to provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Why do this is SQL when you can easily modify in the c# portion of the code.